# How can I get data from a json-file via GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I have:

```
- src
  - data
    - data.json
```

data.json:

```
"gallery": [
    {"name":...
    {"name":.. ...
```

gatsby-config.js contains:

```
`gatsby-transformer-json`,
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    path: `${__dirname}/src/data`,
    name: `data`,
  },
},
```

How can I get list of gallery.names from this json-file via GraphQL query?
I'm trying to write:

```
export const IndexQuery = graphql`
  query IndexQuery {    
    mydata: file(name: { eq: "data" }, extension: { eq: "json" }) {
      allFile {
        gallery {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your GraphQL query needs a little tweaking. The `gatsby-transformer-json` takes care of all the resolving, so you don't need to worry about `gatsby-source-filesystem` inside the query:

```babel
export const IndexQuery = graphql`
  query IndexQuery {
    dataJson {
      gallery {
        name
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Then use it inside the page/layout like:

```babel
this.props.data.dataJson.gallery
```

To debug your GraphQL queries it’s helpful to use the built-in *GraphiQL*, which should run at http://localhost:8000/___graphql.

Comment: const { mydata } = this.props.data.dataJson

    return (<div>
          {mydata.gallery.forEach(value => alert(value.name))}
        </div>)

Comment: Do `console.log(this.props.data.dataJson)` and check what data you get returned. `mydata` does not exist in the query. Try `const { gallery } = this.props.data.dataJson` and loop over that instead.

Comment: We should write `dataJson`, because file name is data.json or directory name?

Comment: Yep, because of the directory name.